# PHP/MYSQL JavaScript - Insert values of multiple dynamic rows into textfields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

As you can see in the JsFiddle, I have a table (it's a static example, but in reality it's dynamic) and it pulls out rows of data from a table.

I want to be able to create one button which will inserts all of the values of the mobile number and the serial number into textfields. so if there are three rows, it will insert them into three rows of textfields. the range of rows can be between 0-20.

I've got as far as inserting them individually into textfields as you can see in the JsFiddle. (tho it doesn't work as theres some php code in there, but it does work!)

http://jsfiddle.net/JGHap/1/

**my button code**

```
<input type="button" value="select" onclick="clickMe('<?php echo $row['sim_mobile_number']; ?>')" />
```

**JS code**

```
function clickMe(number) {
     $("#textfield").val(number);
}
function clickMee(text) {
      $("#serial").val(text);
}
```

I've made this image to help understand what i'm trying to achieve

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. That is, not just in a fiddle. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: thanks for your reply. sorry not getting this, if you're referring to why my jsFiddle isn't working is because the table pulls out values from a db and obviously i cannot connect the my db to jsfiddle, so i've left the php code there for reference

Comment: I mean, you are supposed to put the code _here_, in the question, not just point to a copy/paste service or jsfiddle

Comment: oh okay, i've edited my question and added the relevant pieces of code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/JGHap/5/**

```
<td><div id="placeholder1">AWE_A92839</div><input type="button" id="button1" value="button1" /></td>
```

Comment: keep your promise in chat, you're supposed to love the person who answers this q forever, haha :)

Comment: thanks! <3 but i need something more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JGHap/6/ a textfield for each, and just one button to do all of that, is that possible to do?

Comment: @Siza no, because otherwise you can't know which serial to take :)